# Find $B$ such that $B^* B = A$, where $A= \begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 & -1 \\-1 & 2 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & 2 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let
>
> $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
>          2 & -1 & -1 \\
>         -1 &  2 & -1 \\ 
>         -1 & -1 & 2 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Find $B$ such that $B^* B = A$, where $B^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $B$.

---

I have been at this question for a while. I know that $A$ is self-adjoint (Hermitian) and therefore normal. So $A = VDV^*$. I found the eigenvectors to be

- $x = 0$ with multiplicity $1$
- $x = 3$ with multiplicity $2$

$$  V =                
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$  D =                
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$  V^{-1} =                
\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
-1/3 & 2/3 & -1/3 \\
-1/3 & -1/3 & 2/3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I don't really know what to do now. This is my first time posting, sorry if the formatting is wrong.

Comment: What are $B^*$ and $V^*$?

Comment: The conjugate transpose. Sorry I will edit the post

Comment: But your matrix $V^*$ is **not** the conjugate transpose of $V$.

Comment: Sorry that was suppose to be the inverse

Comment: Imagine everyone is as good as you at posting questions, being clear and concise and with proper $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ formatting. Imagine.

Comment: You can use the fact that $A^2=3A$

Comment: Conventionally, that which is given is denoted using the first letters of the Latin alphabet and that which is unknown is denoted using the last letters of the Latin alphabet. I do not understand why you break from tradition. Lastly, were you the one who posted the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3609648/339790) yesterday from another account?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo No that was not me yesterday.

Comment: Say hi to your classmate, then ;-)

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo "I  do not understand why you do not stick to tradition" is maybe a little exaggerated. There is another "tradition" which is to take the letters in the order of the alphabet, either for given or for unknown quantities, especially in linear algebra (I would not say the same thing for ordinary algebra).

Comment: @JeanMarie Conventional notation contains precious information on types. $m$ and $n$ are integers. $x$ and $y$ are reals. $\bf x$ and $\bf y$ are real vectors. $\bf A$ and $\bf B$ are given matrices. I hate having no information on types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $V$ is $-\lambda ^3+6 \lambda ^2-9 \lambda$, whose roots are $3$ (a double root) and $0$. The vectors $(1,-1,0)$ and $(1,0,-1)$ are linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $3$, and the vector $(1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$. Let$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\-1&0&1\\0&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$$(its columns are the vectors mentioned above). So,$$P^{-1}.A.P=\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$Therefore, you can take$$B=P.\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt3&0&0\\0&\sqrt3&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\end{bmatrix}.$$Since $B$ is a real symmetric matrix, $B^*=B$, and then you have $B^*B=B^2=V$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

There is a very different sort of factorisation which is called Cholesky factorization (or more exactly incomplete Cholesky factorization): you will obtain

$$A=C^TC$$

with an upper triangular matrix $C$ which is :

$$C=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{2}&-\sqrt{1/2}&-\sqrt{1/2}\\0&\sqrt{3/2}&-\sqrt{3/2}\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

This factorization is well known and has many applications. (There are algorithms for obtaining it : [see here](https://algowiki-project.org/en/Cholesky_decomposition)).